# Oracle SQL banding values by stdev at a certain time

Tags: oracle, data-science

On Oracle 11

I have a time series of data where in I have something like:

| cluster | METRIC_DATE | METRIC_HOUR | ERRORS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ECWZ | 2023-02-01 | 22 | 0 |
| ECWZ | 2023-02-01 | 23 | 0 |
| ECWZ | 2023-02-02 | 0 | 1 |
| ECWZ | 2023-02-02 | 1 | 0 |
| ECWZ | 2023-02-02 | 2 | 0 |

```sql
create table MY_TABLE (
    "cluster" varchar2(16) not null,
    metric_date date not null,
    metric_hour int not null,
    errors int default 0
);
```

(inserts at end)

There can be many entries for any given `cluster/date/hour` combo, but I present them here as already summed so the number of test inserts is smaller.

What I am trying to do, in words, is:

> For a given cluster and any given hour of the day, compute a rolling n-week stdev and avg, as well as a +/- .25 stddev about the mean and the total (sum) for each hour

The idea is simply to use stddev as a way to detect anomalies within a band at a given hour, since error counts do naturally vary with use, which varies by time-of-day

So, the ideal output form would be (notice lower, avg, upper all stay constant for their respective hour. This data is not accurate, just representative):

| cluster | metric_date | metric_hour | lower (computed on many weeks) | avg (computed on many weeks) | upper (computed on many weeks) | actual (computed on a single {cluster,date,hour} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FOO | 2023-02-01 | 22 | 1.36650509909417249475426533014395795476 | 2 | 3.63349490090582750524573466985604204524 | 3 |
| FOO | 2023-02-01 | 23 | 3.44321509909417249475426533014395795476 | 4 | 6.63349490090582750524573466985604204524 | 10 |
| FOO | 2023-02-02 | 22 | 1.36650509909417249475426533014395795476 | 2 | 3.63349490090582750524573466985604204524 | 2 |
| FOO | 2023-02-02 | 23 | 3.44321509909417249475426533014395795476 | 4 | 6.63349490090582750524573466985604204524 | 5 |

This computes the statistics for all comparative hours (so, std for hour `11` across the entire data set)

```sql
select "cluster", metric_hour, greatest((avg - (stdev /4)),0) as "lower",avg, avg + (stdev /4) as upper, stdev from (
    select "cluster" , metric_hour, stddev(errors) as stdev, avg(errors) avg
    from MY_TABLE
    group by "cluster", metric_hour
    order by "cluster", metric_hour
);
```

This gets me my value for a given hour. The `actual` is just for that 1 hour.

```sql
select "cluster" , metric_date, metric_hour, sum(errors) as actual
from MY_TABLE
group by "cluster", metric_date, metric_hour
order by "cluster", metric_date, metric_hour;
```

Although the `lower|avg|upper` would all actually be computed based on weeks of data, grouped by cluster and hour,
the `actual` is only on a given hour

Presenting it this way would simplify graphing/reporting since I wouldn't have to overlay 2 reports
and it's easier to grok.

**The question:** how do I marry these queries together into 1 result, where each query is aggregating entirely different data sets? Oh, to make this more interesting, any gaps in data are assumed to be 0

my WIP query:

```sql
select *
from ((select "cluster", metric_date, metric_hour, lower, avg, upper, stdev,sum(errors) as actual
       from MY_TABLE
       group by "cluster", metric_date, metric_hour
       order by "cluster", metric_date, metric_hour)
      union all
      (select "cluster",
              metric_hour,
              greatest((avg - (stdev / 4)), 0) as "lower",
              avg,
              avg + (stdev / 4)                as upper,
              stdev
       from (
                select "cluster", metric_hour, stddev(errors) as stdev, avg(errors) avg
                from MY_TABLE
                group by "cluster", metric_hour
                order by "cluster", metric_hour
       ))

)
```

insert data:

```sql
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2002-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '14', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2004-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '16', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2004-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '20', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2005-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '20', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2006-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '6', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2008-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '6', 8);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2013-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2014-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2017-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '20', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2017-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '22', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2019-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '11', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2021-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '10', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2021-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2027-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('FOO', TO_DATE('2027-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '9', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2001-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '10', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2002-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '19', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2002-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '22', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2003-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '18', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2004-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '2', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2008-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '21', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2012-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '8', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2013-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2014-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '2', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2015-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '7', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2020-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 1);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2021-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '6', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2027-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '14', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2027-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAZ', TO_DATE('2028-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '23', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAT', TO_DATE('2004-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '19', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAT', TO_DATE('2015-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '8', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAT', TO_DATE('2019-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '2', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAR', TO_DATE('2001-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '13', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAR', TO_DATE('2002-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '17', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAR', TO_DATE('2017-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAR', TO_DATE('2018-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '20', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAR', TO_DATE('2021-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '16', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BAR', TO_DATE('2027-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '12', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2001-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '18', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2001-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '8', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2009-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2009-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '7', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2013-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '18', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2021-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '22', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2022-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '16', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('BLAH', TO_DATE('2022-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '21', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('ABCD', TO_DATE('2003-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '15', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2001-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '9', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2001-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2001-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '8', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2002-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '1', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2003-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2004-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '0', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2007-03-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '23', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2009-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '12', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2017-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '19', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2024-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '11', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2025-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '19', 0);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE("cluster", METRIC_DATE, METRIC_HOUR, ERRORS) VALUES ('DEFG', TO_DATE('2026-02-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), '23', 0);

commit;
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood everything correctly, but you need something like [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/grn6C_aH). Rows generator, left join your data, group, finally analytic functions with partition clause.

Comment: I think that'll do it. I am double checking it now. If you want credit, post as an answer